# Склеивание нескольких изображений в одно

Tags: c#, wpf, изображения, bitmap

Мне нужно собрать из 9 Bitmap 1 изображение и сохранить его на жёсткий диск, как это осуществить?

Comment: Например при помощи ImageMagic можно "склеивать" изображения.

Comment: складываете размеры 9-ти изображений. создаете Bitmap такого размера и в него выводите 9-ть изображений.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Media;

var files = new[] { @"c:\temp\1.jpg", @"c:\temp\2.jpg" };

var dv = new DrawingVisual();
using (var dc = dv.RenderOpen()) {
    double left = 0;
    foreach (var file in files) {
        var bi = new BitmapImage(new Uri(file, UriKind.Absolute));
        dc.DrawImage(bi, new Rect(left, 0, bi.Width, bi.Height));
        left += bi.Width;
    }
}

var rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)dv.ContentBounds.Width,
                (int)dv.ContentBounds.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
rtb.Render(dv);

var en = new PngBitmapEncoder();
en.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));

using (var s = File.Create(@"C:\Temp\result.png"))
    en.Save(s);
```